# Difference between "anche io" and "anch'io"

Tags: word-choice, difference, abbreviations

I have seen both forms being used: "anche io" and "anch'io". In theory they are both correct, but I was wondering if one of them is more common/natural/informal than the other one, from a native Italian perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon you are inquiring about is called *elision* (*elisione* in Italian). According to Luca Serianni in section I.72 of his book *Italiano*

> L'elisione è la perdita – fonetica e grafica – della vocale finale atona di una parola davanti alla vocale iniziale della parola seguente. Nella scrittura va obbligatoriamente indicata con l'apostrofo

That is,

> Elision represents the loss – both phonetic and graphic – of the unstressed final vowel of a word when it is followed by an initial vowel in the next word. In writing, this must be indicated with an apostrophe.

In section II.72 of the same book, Serianni explains

> L'elisione grafica è normale con gli articoli singolari e con le relative preposizioni articolate (*l'oro*, *nell'età*, *un'amica*; poco comune al plurale e per il maschile solo davanti a *i*: *gl'Italiani*, *l'erbe* [cfr. IV.4, IV.5]); con gli aggettivi dimostrativi singolari *questo*, *questa*, *quello*, *quella* (*quest'asino*, *quell'epoca*); con *bello*, *bella* (*bell'uomo*, *bell'idea*); con *santo*, *santa* (*sant'Antonio*, *sant'Anna*); con *come* e *ci* davanti al verbo *essere* (*com'è andata?*, *c'è*, *c'erano*); in una serie di espressioni idiomatiche: *a quattr'occhi*, *l'altr'anno*, *tutt'altro*, +*senz'altro* e *nient'altro*, *mezz'ora*, ecc. 
> In altri casi l'elisione è sempre facoltativa e appare in declino rispetto all'uso di un secolo fa

That is,

> Graphic elision is normal with singular articles and their combined prepositions (*l'oro*, *nell'età*, *un'amica*; it's rare in the plural form and for the masculine gender, only before *i*: *gl'Italiani*, *l'erbe* [cf. IV.4, IV.5]); with singular demonstrative adjectives *questo*, *questa*, *quello*, *quella* (*quest'asino*, *quell'epoca*); with *bello*, *bella* (*bell'uomo*, *bell'idea*); with *santo*, *santa* (*sant'Antonio*, *sant'Anna*); with *come* and *ci* before the verb *essere* (*com'è andata?*, *c'è*, *c'erano*); in a series of idiomatic expressions: *a quattr'occhi*, *l'altr'anno*, *tutt'altro*, +*senz'altro* e *nient'altro*, *mezz'ora*, etc. 
> In other cases, elision is always optional and appears to be in decline compared to its usage a century ago.

[*Si dice o non si dice?*](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/C/ch-io-ch-egli.shtml), a reference book by [Aldo Gabrielli](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Gabrielli),  mentions *anch'io* as an instance of elision that is still common. Indeed, having a look to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anche+io%2C+anch%27io&year_start=1800&year_end=2005&corpus=it-2012&smoothing=5&case_insensitive=true), you can realize that *anch'io* is much more used that the non elided version *anche io*.

Comment: Thanks! That last paragraph was exactly what I needed.